# QT slot ignores while loop

Tags: multithreading, qt

Hello i'm try to create an application in QT with two thread but i have an issue :
 I have a slot which run when i click on a pushbutton, and on the click it is supposed to change the name of a label called lValeur. But it change the text only once . Play help me i want to die ...

Here is the interesting part of my code :

```
    void IHM::ClicButtonPer()
{
    ButtonDem->setEnabled(true) ;
    ButtonPer->setEnabled(false) ;
    QString val ;
    QTimer attendre ;
    do
    {
        val = "Valeur : " ;
        val += valeur ;
        lValeur->setText(val) ;
        attendre.start(1000) ;
        while(attendre.isActive())
            QApplication::processEvents() ;
        if(ButtonPer->isEnabled())
            break ;
    }while(1) ;
}
```

and the connect function which execute the slot :

`connect(ButtonPer, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ClicButtonPer())) ;`

EDIT : that's multithreading because i have another thread which communicate with a TCP server

EDIT 2 :

`connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &IHM::on_timer);`

this code just return me an error on &IHM::on_timer: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'void'

EDIT 3 (and the last one) :

I change `connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &IHM::on_timer);`
with `connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_timer)) ;`
Hope it will help someone

Comment: My advice is to get rid of both of the loops.

Comment: This is not really multithreading. There is only 1 thread.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange code. You need to learn the basics of programming. A timer is an entity that is not used in loops. Timers are usually used to repeatedly perform any action at predetermined equal intervals of time, but avoiding loops.

**As for Qt and the QTimer class**,
you need to create a QTimer object in a nonlocal scope. You can add the variable declaration to the IHM class header. In the simplest case, you also need to create a slot method.

```
class IHM : public...
{
     ...
private:
    QTimer m_timer;

private slots:
    void on_timer();
}
```

Then in the IHM cpp file you need to connect the `timeout` signal of the timer the slot. It can be done in the IHM constructor.

```
connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &IHM::on_timer);
```

Put the code you need to be called repeatedly, to the slot body. Start and stop the timer wherever you need. For example:

```
void IHM::ClicButtonPer()
{
    ...
    m_timer.start(1000);
}

void IHM::on_timer()
{
    ...
    val += valeur;
    lValeur->setText(val);

    if(ButtonPer->isEnabled())
    {
        m_timer.stop();
    }     
}
```

As for the issue **"it change the text only once"** you need to read about Qt event loop. I can suggest
[Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)
[Threads_Events_QObjects](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects).
You can also set a breakpoint to the line `attendre.start(1000);` then go down the steps and see what conditions are actually met.

Read also:
[Threading Basics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)
[Multithreading Technologies in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html)
[Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help me i know i'm not that good because i'm a student and QT is new for me